# TestContainers neo4j static URI

Tags: java, spring, neo4j, testcontainers

I am using neo4j test containers for the integration tests.
Con someone help me to figure out how to configure this container to use the same port every time. Currently when I am running tests the bolt URI has different ports.

Comment: that's the main core idea behind testcontainers . If you are using spring boot with neo4j then this can help to test your apps https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-test-autoconfigure/src/test/java/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/data/neo4j/DataNeo4jTestIntegrationTests.java#L52-L55

Comment: Thanks, I was using this approach and it's working. I was thinking if it's possible to setup for the container just a permanent port

Comment: Using a fixed port with Testcontainers is generally not possible and is strictly discouraged. Why would you want a fixed port? The solution shared above should work fine and avoid the potential for port conflicts in different scenarios.